# Expo SDK 44, App rejected by google for Accessing Background Location

Tags: android, expo

I am building an Expo app which requests location on app foreground state. I published app first on Google and SDK version was 42, but now when I upgraded SDK to 44, google responds with a warning that app uses Background Location access. I had done this location work at SDK 42, No issues were highlighted.

I am using `expo-location` and following is my `app.json` config for android.

```
    "android": {
      "package": "<package-name>",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "versionCode": 3,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "splash": {
        "mdpi": "./assets/splash-mdpi.png",
        "hdpi": "./assets/splash-hdpi.png",
        "xhdpi": "./assets/splash-xhdpi.png",
        "xxhdpi": "./assets/splash-xxhdpi.png",
        "xxxhdpi": "./assets/splash-xxxhdpi.png",
        "resizeMode": "cover"
      },
    },
```

[Heres the image of error from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNc4N.png)

Answer (score 0):

Expo's automatically added `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission to AndroidManifest.xml. So you have to declare permissions in `app.json` to override it.

```
    "android": {
      "package": "<package-name>",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "<I'm not sure that you have to declare all anothers here or not>"
      ],
```

Comment: Well actucally it was package issue, so I found an article (I lost the link).
which stated that by running this commad would solve this issue.

`sed -i -e "s/.*ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION.*/return true;/g" node_modules/expo-location/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/location/LocationModule.java`